# How to create re-authentication in Twitter?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a query that I want to set re-authentication in my website like this:

If i registered once in my website and link my account with twitter then next time I logged into the website I would not need to log in with twitter. It will be automatically connected with  twitter.

Answer (score 0):

You'll still need to authenticate with twitter each time, but you can save the users `oauthtoken` and `oauthtoken secret` to a mySQL database so you don't have to ask the user to authenticate manually. The keys, if you will, never expire. Your apps authentication can however be revoked by the twitter user. Here's a helpful [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/) on getting setup from scratch. Some of the first steps have changed, but "Registering users" section will be helpful to you.

Comment: but there is no re authentication done in this tutorial because when i logged in with this twitter SDK i automatically connected with twitter account so no re authentication done in this tutorial. if u have any other idea to create long access token for twitter then please suggest me with suitable examples or tutorials.